# C# WCF with ADFS authentication local

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, authentication, adfs

I'm trying to implement WCF application with ADFS authentication. On installing ADFS in my local machine it says that it requires windows server 2008 R2 version is required. Is there is any other way to implement the same and test it in local.

P.S I'm trying to implement it in my local machine for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a virtual machine server to have all in one.
2. I don't know what you are looking for exactly, because if you wcf pourpose it's to use adfs service, you don't need to install localy, only need a domain server that have installed.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for info @Javier, but now I'm stuck with another problem. I'm referring the following link: [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2011/08/17/federated-security-how-to-setup-and-call-a-wcf-service-secured-by-adfs-2-0/) for ADFS authentication in WCF. I have skipped setting up ADFS step (hope it is not necessary in local environment) I have created a WCF service and installed WIF SDK. But I couldn't able to find "Add STS Reference" in project node. Is there is any alternative way or am I missing something I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Express and Visual Studio 2013 Profession

Comment: You need install adfs on the ad server. Install WIF on local. Restart machine, sometime that is the key. For use the services, create in your visual studio a website, pay attention it's not a project application type it's a website in File -> New website, of type wcf, the version of framework that create the application have to be 4.0 not other. And Then in the node project in solution explorer you watch add sts reference.

Answer (score 0):

What version of ADFS do you want to use?

You cannot install ADFS on a desktop. It has to be installed on a server. ADFS sits on top of AD so you need a DC as well. You can have this all on the same server.

That link refers to VS 2010. That feature is no longer there. You need to use "Change Authentication" / "On Premises" as per [this](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/).

Comment: I'm ok with ADFS 2.0 or 3.0. I'm trying to create a WCF application and I couldn't able to find a way to set On-Premises authentication. Is it possible to apply this authentication in WCF application or am I missing some steps.

Comment: Do you have VS 2010 or 2012? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/how-to-enable-wif-for-a-wcf-web-service-application

Comment: You may have to do this manually - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/distributedservices/2012/08/31/wif-tips-on-adding-a-service-reference-to-a-claims-aware-wcf-service/